# quantity of `Around` with "DimensionlessUnit"

Tags: units

```
Quantity[1, "DimensionlessUnit"]
```

gives pure number

```
1
```

However,

```
Quantity[Around[1, 0.1], "DimensionlessUnit"]
```

still gives

```
Quantity[Around[0.01`, 0.001`], "DimensionlessUnit"]
```

instead of pure `Around` expression. Why?

This will cause some unintended behavior like

```
Quantity[1, "g"]*Quantity[1, "cm"]/Quantity[Around[1, 0.1], "m"]
```

will give

```
Quantity[Around[0.01`, 0.001`], Times["DimensionlessUnit", "Grams"]]
```

with "DimensionlessUnit" still present instead of simple

```
Quantity[Around[0.01`, 0.001`], "Grams"]
```

Is there some fix for this annoying "DimensionlessUnit" when dealing with `Around` expressions?

Comment: I realize a simple fix would be `Unprotect[Quantity];
Quantity[x_Around, "DimensionlessUnit"] := x`

Comment: I think your proposed fix is the correct solution (followed by `Protect[Quantity]`).  You should report it as an issue to Wolfram.